# trying to select combobox's item with onclick instead dbclick [Extjs]

Tags: javascript, extjs, combobox

i'm trying to select my `combobox` items with only one click, but, when clicked once, this doesn't works, just when i click two times this has been selected, but i don't need that. But, here's an interesting (weird) thing, sometimes works with one click and other times with the double click.

here's my code:

```
    items: [{
    xtype: 'combo',
    anchor: '100%',
    padding: 10,
    fieldLabel: 'Type',
    name: 'fieldType',
    labelStyle: "font-weight:bold;",
    store: new Ext.data.Store({
        fields: [{
            name: 'description',
            type: 'string'
        }, {
            name: 'name',
            type: 'string'
        }, {
            name: 'uuid',
            type: 'string'
        }],
        autoLoad: true,
        hideTrigger: true,
        minChars: 1,
        triggerAction: 'query',
        typeAhead: true,
        proxy: {
            type: 'ajax',
            url: "../",
            extraParams: {
                action: "catalog",
                catalog: "fieldtypeoptions",
                params: JSON.stringify({
                    uuidToken: Ext.connectionToken
                })
            },
            reader: {
                type: 'json',
                root: 'dataTypesList'
            },
            listeners: {
                exception: function(proxy, response, operation, eOpts) {
                    var responseArray = JSON.parse(response.responseText);
                    Ext.Notify.msg(responseArray.message, {
                        layout: "bottomright",
                        delay: 5000,
                        type: "error"
                    });
                }
            },
        }
    }),
    typeAhead: true,
    triggerAction: 'all',
    valueField: 'uuid',
    displayField: 'description',
    listeners: {
        change: function(combo, value) {
            console.log(value);
            console.log(combo);
            console.log(combo.getValue());
        },
        click: function() {
            alert('One click event');
        }
    },
    element: 'combo'
}, {
    xtype: 'fieldcontainer',
    anchor: "100%",
    layout: 'hbox',
    padding: 10,
    fieldDefaults: {
        msgTarget: 'under',
        labelAlign: 'top'
    },
    items: [{
        xtype: 'numberfield',
        minValue: 0,
        maxValue: 100,
        emptyText: 'Length',
        name: 'length',
        allowBlank: false,
        flex: 1,
        listeners: {
            afterrender: function(field) {
                Ext.create('Ext.tip.ToolTip', {
                    target: field.getId(),
                    html: 'Length'
                });
            }
        }
    }, {
        xtype: 'numberfield',
        emptyText: 'Decimal',
        name: 'decimal',
        minValue: 0,
        allowBlank: false,
        maxValue: 100,
        flex: 1,
        listeners: {
            afterrender: function(field) {
                Ext.create('Ext.tip.ToolTip', {
                    target: field.getId(),
                    html: 'Decimal'
                });
            }
        }
    }]
}]
```

I'm newbie with extjs, so, i just don't know for what reason this is happening... so, if anyone can help me with this, i'll be very grateful!

UPDATE:

I've seen my console, so i found some problem..

The problem:

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'fields' of null

and theoritically, the problem is over here:

```
    classifyFields: function (field, list) {
            var me = this;
            var type = null;
 // the next if, it is assumed is the problem.
            if (field.fields.variableLengthField) {
                type = "variableLenghtField";
            } else if (field.fields.journalSaved) {
                type = "journalField";
            }
            console.log(type, field, list);
            list.forEach(function (item) {
                if (item.name == type) {
                    me.dataFields.push({
                        "uuidFielMonitorType": item.uuid,
                        "fieldProperties": field.fields
                    });
                }
            });
            console.log(me.dataFields);
        }
```

Comment: Maybe you have some js errors in a console? Also what extjs version are you using?

Comment: in fact, yup, i have this problem in my console: ( **Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'fields' of null** ) , btw, i'm using extjs 4.2! :)

Comment: Do you know how to fix it? Add some null checks?

Comment: not yet, in fact, i'm still trying to understand the problem with that property called 'fields'. :/

Comment: How and where do you use `classifyFields` function?